# Take android app name/package from a running process

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-package-managers

I want to ask if it's there any way to do a background process in Android that each time i open an app to understand it and show a flash message, lets say, with the process name or package name of this app.
Than you in advance.

Comment: You can get the main package name from `ps` or by trolling through /proc as ps does yourself.  But just because there is a process associated with something doesn't mean it is active, and just because there isn't a process doesn't mean that Android doesn't consider it supposed to be active.

Comment: can you give more info about `ps` from where i can read?

Comment: You can try it with `adb shell ps` otherwise do a web search - however, as I was trying to explain the information may not be as useful as you think.

Comment: ok, thank you i will have a look of it

Comment: but if i do the `ps` in my service it will return the PID of my service and not the app that the user has open.

Comment: Normally it will return everything.  If you encounter a hypothetical setting where it has been locked down to only return your own, then that would be probably be a part of a broader and intentional effort to make your goal unachievable on that system.

Comment: but if i return everything which process i will know that is the currently open by the user?

Comment: ok i found it here
`ActivityManager am2 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am2.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();`